# How to use Akka future without providing time parameter?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, future

I have a 2 main actors(main worker,sec main worker)-

1.main worker to divide sample group to individual samples
2.sec main worker gets an sample and does the processing.(using sub workers)

**Issue: I want the main worker to wait to load any new sample group until old sample group is completed. And the time taken to process each sample group varies.How to use futures in this scenario? Each main worker send sample group completed message at the end of completing an sample group.**

Can futures be used in such scenarios when time constrain is not known? I am new to futures and most of the examples of futures i searched had some time mentioned in them.

Comment: Do you have "two" `ActorSystem`s or do you have two types of actors... ? I don't think you should be looking at two different actor systems. Also... this looks like a classical case of worker driven work distribution problem... this pattern is very beautifully explained and implemented in these blogs - http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2 and http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/

Comment: About futures... Yes futures can be used. But I don't think you should use futures here since you need a wroker-pull driven scheduling of work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario example that does not rely on the futures or timing:

Scenario example:

Actor1 splits the sample group and keeps a collection of samples
in receive you can get a request for a new sample from Actor2 and remove it from the current collection of samples.
When the collection of samples is empty you can request a new sample group.

Actor2 has the same collection mecanism for keeping track of completed work on the current sample, each time a subworker completes a task remove it from the collection. When the collection gets empty request a new sample from Actor1

You may want to schedule a timeout on the Actor2 so if it does not have messages for more than an interval then you can throw an error or retry processing the sample again.